# Dense_rank in a 2nd query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query the pulls data from 2 separate tables and puts them into a 3rd table using dense_rank as a way of grouping patient claim lines together. The problem I'm running into is in the 2nd query, the dense_rank starts over again at "1" instead of picking up where the 1st query ended.

```
 select
  'somenumber'+ right('000000' + cast(dense_rank()OVER(order by o.column1) as varchar(6)),6) AS rank_id
  ,'Y' as error_flag
  ,o.column2
  ,o.column3
  ,o.column4
  ,o.column5
  ,o.column6
  ,o.column7
  ,p.column8
  ,q.column9
  ,r.column10
  into #temp_table

  FROM main_table o
        LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table p  ON o.blah=p.blah
        LEFT OUTER JOIN another_table q ON o.snooze=q.snooze
        LEFT OUTER JOIN im_confused r ON o.help_me=r.help_me

  where o.column11='somenumber'
```

Would it just be easier to include another join for the 2nd table where the dense_rank starts over again or can dense_rank be manipulated to pick up where the 1st one left off?

Comment: which version of mysql are you using that allows dense_rank()?

Comment: I apologize - MySQL was added as a tag accidentally.

Comment: If your query is big enough, can you post a minimal example?

Comment: @McNets - a pared-down version of the query has been added. I know columns may not match up but I'm more concerned about knowing if the 2nd query (which is identical except for the "from" source) can have the dense_rank pick up where the 1st query ended.

Comment: is there a way to find out last inserted rank?

Comment: @McNets - I don't know but I decided to use a temp table so that I have everything in 1 table before doing the dense_rank. Probably not the most ideal or efficient way of doing it but then again, duct tape is popular for a reason: it works. Thanks for wracking your brain on this for me. I will continue to research.

Answer (score 0):

Just used a temp table and then performed the dense_rank upon inserting into the final table. Solved the problem but the question still remains - can you manipulate a dense_rank?